# change comma to colon after (year) using biblatex.sty

Tags: biblatex

My tags are:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,%style=numeric,
style=ext-numeric,%
citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,autolang=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{acerbi2014origins,
  title={On the Origins of Suboptimality in Human Probabilistic Inference},
  author={Acerbi, Luigi and Vijayakumar, Sethu and Wolpert, Daniel M.},
  journal={PLoS Computational Biology},
  volume={10},
  number={6},
  pages={e1003661},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Public Library of Science San Francisco, USA}
}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
       \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\newcommand*{\aftertitlepunct}{\addperiod\space}
\newcommand*{\afterbooktitlepunct}{\aftertitlepunct}
\newcommand*{\aftermaintitlepunct}{\aftertitlepunct}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibsstring{number}~#1}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase:title]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase:title]{subtitle}}%
     \setunit{\titleaddonpunct}}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printunit{\aftertitlepunct}}}

\renewbibmacro*{booktitle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[booktitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase:booktitle]{booktitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase:booktitle]{booksubtitle}}%
     \setunit{\titleaddonpunct}}%
  \printfield{booktitleaddon}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printunit{\afterbooktitlepunct}}}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It produced the output as:

[image]

I need to change the marked comma to colon, please advise...

Comment: I checked for you MWE and `\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}` also works there.

Comment: @Marijn Yes, it works well, sorry for the existing question, shall I remove my question?